# video.captureStream becomes pitch green when sending through WebRTC

Tags: javascript, canvas, video, webrtc

My product has a tool that allows you to share a video via WebRTC. When we first deployed it, we tried using a code like the following:

```js
this.videoEl = document.createElement("video");
this.videoEl.src = url;

this.videoEl.oncanplay = function() {
    this.oncanplay = undefined;
    this.mediaStream = this.videoEl.captureStream();
};
```

The issue is that when sending this `mediaStream`, the result is a pitch green video, but with working audio:

[image]

The solution we came up with is to create a canvas and draw to our canvas the video contents, something like this:

```js
this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
this.videoEl = document.createElement("video");
this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
this.videoEl.src = url;

this.videoEl.oncanplay = function() {
    this.oncanplay = undefined;
    
    // Some code (stripping a lot of unnecessary stuff)

    // Canvas drawing loop
    this.canvas.width = this.videoEl.videoWidth;
    this.canvas.height = this.videoEl.videoHeight;
    this.ctx.drawImage(this.videoEl, 0, 0, this.videoEl.videoWidth, this.videoEl.videoHeight);
    // Loop ends and more code

    // Media stream element
    this.mediaStream = this.canvas.captureStream(25);

    // Attached audio track to Media Stream
    try {
        var audioContext = new AudioContext();
        this.gainNode = audioContext.createGain(); 

        audioSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(this.videoEl.captureStream(25));
        audioDestination = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();
        audioSource.connect(this.gainNode);
        this.gainNode.connect(audioDestination);
        this.gainNode.gain.value = 1;

        this.mediaStream.addTrack(audioDestination.stream.getAudioTracks()[0]);

    } catch (e) {
        // No audio tracks found
        this.noAudio = true;
    }
};
```

The solution works, however it consumes a lot of CPU and it would be great to avoid having to write all of that code. We also have customers complaining that the audio gets out of sync sometimes (which is understandable since I'm using a `captureStream` for audio and not for video.

At first I thought it was green because it was tainting the `MediaStream`, but that's not the case since I can normally draw the video to a canvas and capturing a `MediaStream` from it. PS: We are using a `URL.createObjectURL(file)` call to get the video url.

Do you know why the video is green?
Thanks.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1156408 -- potentially this known bug

Answer (score 2):

It turns out it's a [Google Chrome Bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1156408).
Thanks to Philipp Hancke.